# Halp! The favicon is borked!

Tags: bug, status-completed, favicon

When I opened up the site-switcher, the first thing I noticed was that the MSO favicon was actually the MSE favicon. <strike>This seems to validate my theory that this "mse-mso-split" is actually a scam, and all you really did was add some fancy new graphics and change the domain of MSO to MSE.</strike>

> [image]

plz fix.

Okay, it's also borked in other places:

> [image]

**Y U no fi**—Oh, wait, you just did.

Comment: ... wait a bit for them to fix it. Plz?

Comment: Give them a bit of time to work things out. It hasn't quite been an hour yet, and I'm sure they're aware.

Comment: @Emracool Give them moar time? NO WAI! They'll just end up taking another six to eight weeks.

Comment: @hichris123 I think they've had plenty of time, after all the switch happened a year ago... (as evidenced by my having the yearling badge already)

Comment: @0x7fffffff Then I stand corrected. Go ahead and complain! Hey, the homepage doesn't work! Fixy plz?

Comment: So, congratulation for first meta-SO post? Edit: never mind, somehow I have 1-post-per-pagination and I thought this is the only post -_-

Comment: @AndrewT. Nope: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250001

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks for the report.  We found we had a few settings that were missed during this tricky migration.  It should be ok now.

Answer (score 11):

Okay, I found out why this is and how it can be fixed. Just change all the borked favicon's `div`'s `favicon-stackexchangemeta` class to `favicon-stackoverflowmeta`.

Comment: [Shog9](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) is the guy with the hat.  You're just an imposter.